# udev rules in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev

I was setting up some udev rules in Ubuntu 12.04 for my APC UPSs and I was using the included `*-net.rules` as reference.  When I used `ATTR{}==""` matching in my `-ups.rules` though it didn't work, I had to switch to `ATTRS{}==""` to get it to work.

Now I'm wondering:

- Is the system built in `udev` rules for `eth0` and `eth1` broken?
- Should they be using `ATTRS` instead of `ATTR`?
- How would I check to make sure they are working?
- How do I even list the `ATTRS` for the network devices? I can't find a device node on which to run `udevadm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at udev's manpage:

```
ATTR{filename}
       Match sysfs attribute values of the event device. Trailing
       whitespace in the attribute values is ignored, if the specified
       match value does not contain trailing whitespace itself.
```

vs

```
ATTRS{filename}
       Search the devpath upwards for a device with matching sysfs
       attribute values. If multiple ATTRS matches are specified, all of
       them must match on the same device. Trailing whitespace in the
       attribute values is ignored, if the specified match value does not
       contain trailing whitespace itself.
```

`ATTR{}` only looks at the node being added. `ATTRS{}` searches the tree. It's probably that your UPS needed `ATTRS{}` because the sysfs attribute that you needed wasn't at the node that you specified.